# A bug while hovering over tags; tooltip is going over pages border creating scrollbar which is impossible to access using mouse or keyboard

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design

I am using a small screen from Remote Desktop with resolution 800x600 (I have my reasons, please don't point out why/how ect...) and while I am trying to display definition of each tag it makes my screen unreadable, because it creates a scroll bar which cannot be reached by using a mouse pointer nor using a arrows which make my tooltip information disappear.

I am using Firefox 8.0.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

This is another problem [I have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114636/174102) [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114711/174102) while browsing this network in small screen.

Comment: This happens on a regular session (Chrome in Windows 7) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your particular case ([as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114826/115866)) is below the threshold screen width that we support, this also (as ChrisF notes) happend with a width of 1024px. That's fixed in the next build.