# Header's background doesn't render properly if browser window under about 980px wide

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All Stack Exchange sites in a small window causing display problems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114636/all-stack-exchange-sites-in-a-small-window-causing-display-problems)

For a while I've noticed if my browser window is so narrow I see a vertical scroll bar, SE sites' headers look like this:
[image]

The problem is the background is the width of your browser window, even though the header is a fixed width of 980px~. So it scales larger perfectly but not smaller.

The problem seems to be the `.container` class. Setting `min-width:1000px` on the `container` fixed this issue on  https://ux.stackexchange.com/, and a min width of  `990px` fixed it on Beta sites ( the value is the header's width + margin/padding).

Fix seems slightly different on different sites; Stack Overflow's css was different again, but the bug affects all sites. Maybe I'm just adding the min-width to the wrong element though.

Comment: @TimStone this one has a fix though :/ seems silly to decline one line of CSS that won't affect anyone with a wide window anyway.

Comment: Still technically a duplicate, but since I totally agree with you I've removed the comment. :P

Comment: You browse the site like that? Wow. :P

Comment: @Alenanno Sometimes I use the site with windows split to half the screen (Win 7 Windows + left/right arrow).