# grey bar is not all across on the top

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All Stack Exchange sites in a small window causing display problems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114636/all-stack-exchange-sites-in-a-small-window-causing-display-problems)

The grey bar at the top of the screen is not stretching all the way to the right when the browser is more narrow than the page - instead it stretches only to the width of the window, making the search bar look odd.

[image]

Comment: What browser? Did you try with other browsers?

Comment: Well, to sum it up: "[The minimum screen width we support is 1024 pixels](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114826/152859)"