# Top Bar background does not persist when scrolling horizontally

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

**Update**

<strike>A month</strike> Several months later, a new top bar, and the bug still exists. An answer has already been posted that would fix the bug, so is this something that the dev team plans on fixing?

There are also a host of other problems caused by this, especially on the [footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209347/meta-and-stack-overflow-footer-broken?lq=1) and [CC-logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209254/cc-logo-position-is-incorrect?lq=1). Again, this would be fixed with

```
html{min-width:1000px;}
```

There is a slight bug with small windows on both the new meta and main site(s)?, shown here. The problem is that the top bar coloring doesn't stretch across when you resize and scroll left or right.

> [image]

On Meta, when a horizontal scroll bar is needed, the black background will only be as wide as the width of the viewport, but when you scroll the coloring will not shift.

To reproduce:

1. Make screen as large as possible, or wait until the menu bar starts expanding
2. Make it smaller and smaller until horizontal scrollbar appears, then scroll left and right.

Comment: I see red outlines, but I don't see what they're referring to. Can you expand? Also use some text description too so that if people also want to report the same thing then when they search to see if it's been reported before it'll come up in the search results. Pictures don't.

Comment: @JonW it has to do with the coloring of the bar not stretching across the entire screen

Comment: Oh... I see it too. Nice find! @JonW make your browser window width small and then scroll right.

Comment: How small? What browser? I wasn't able to reproduce with 1024x768 in Chrome 31 and IE10. When reporting design/CSS bugs please always include browser details.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Resize until you need a scrollbar, then scroll to the right.

Comment: @Stijn I see, this should be in the post itself. (now it is)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Reproduced in safari as well

Comment: @helloworld yeah, this one appears to be "pure CSS" bug, meaning cross browser.

Comment: This seems to be basically a duplicate of [All Stack Exchange sites in a small window causing display problems?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114636/all-stack-exchange-sites-in-a-small-window-causing-display-problems). However, since that question is kind of old and stale, I've voted to close it as a duplicate of this one instead. Anyway, the fix I included in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) for that bug fixes this one too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a very, very easy solution to fixing this and any other background problems that might exist on the site:

```
html { min-width: 1000px }
```

This would make the HTML root element 20px larger than the standard 980px site width, so that even on small screens all elements of the site will expand and encompass the full width of the site.

Comment: +1 - Confirmed that this works for the entire width of the bar. Very light weight as well.

Comment: Trying to get hired? ;)

Comment: This will go live in the next build.