# CC-logo position is incorrect

Tags: bug, design, footer

**Update** *(2014-01-27)*: Now that the [logo is gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217607/230957), the bug still remains. It's as if there should be a scrollbar, but there's none, so it shows white background instead. (On a tablet, so no scrollbar should even be applied to the body)

The cc-wiki logo on my tablet (Nexus 7 2013, Android 4.4, Chrome) is shifted outside the body element breaking the 100% width for the whole page. It's not a big problem, but it's annoying seeing an empty white bar on the right edge of the screen.

It happens at least on MSO and SO, but not on Arqade. The page is fully zoomed out, and display resolution is 1920x1200, so it shouldn't be a too small issue.

[image: cc-wiki footer]

Here you can see both topbar and footer not fully extending:

[image: footer and topbar not fully extended]

Comment: Isn't it the grey area above it that's not extending far enough?

Comment: @Bart I figured it's probably the logo extending too far rather than the *whole* page extending not far enough. The whole body of the page isn't 100%

Comment: Can reproduce in PC when resizing the screen to have horizontal scroll bar (e.g. 800 pixels wide) then the gray will cover only the "first" part and won't extend when scrolling. :/

Comment: Highly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208203/152859 most likely the workaround there will also solve this one.

Comment: It's not a small resolution browser, though, and I can't apply custom CSS or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Like the question I had about the top bar, this could also be answered with this simple CSS change

```
html{
    min-width:1000px;
}
```

Comment: That would probably work.