# Why don’t we call our licence by name?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, creative-commons, licensing

Why does Stack Exchange use this weird “cc-wiki” euphemism instead of calling the CC-BY-SA by its real name?

[image]

<sub>This is a bug report disguised as a question. As in: please fix the footer.</sub>

Comment: Call it where? The icon is a link, did you click it? It leads to a page clearly stating "Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0)" - full enough?

Comment: There are specific logos for cc-by-sa though @ShaWizDowArd. http://creativecommons.org/about/downloads

Comment: @Bart so he should have mentioned this in the question, better revise this to something like "please change the Creative Commons icon from X to Y", unless I still miss the point.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd “cc-wiki” is not the name of the licence.

Comment: Any reason why you removed the link @kinokijuf?

Comment: OK, clear now and making some sense. +1 and close vote retracted.

Comment: @Bart I wasn’t asking about the logo. I’ve seen custom licence logos enough times in my life.

Comment: So .... cc-wiki is fine if it's a logo?

Comment: @Bart. No. It is misleading. I meant that i have seen lots of custom logos that nevertheless said “CC-BY-SA”.

Comment: @kinokijuf, you can read both the tag Meta uses, and the text you quoted to see the proper spelling of `license`, but I'm not getting into an edit war over it.  If you like misspellings in your title, go wild.

Comment: @LanceRoberts see [this](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/licence_license.htm). The noun is spelled with a "c" while the verb with "s" so looks like kino here is correct.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, looks like an edge case for the UK only, as per your link.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Spelling the noun with an “s” is a US-only edge case. All other countries in the world use the propel spelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dunno when exactly, but it was fixed and rolled out to all sites:

> [image]

Answer (score 16):

[As far as I can tell](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/cc-licenses/2005-October/002675.html), "cc-wiki" is an old working name for the license that eventually became [CC-By-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).  According to [an article in *The Wikipedia Signpost* on March 25, 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_Signpost/2005-03-21/CC-Wiki_license):

> "Last Thursday, [Creative Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons) introduced a beta version of its [new license](http://creativecommons.org/drafts/wiki_0.5) designed specifically for [wikis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki), in conjunction with [Lawrence Lessig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Lessig)'s introduction of a wiki to help draft an updated version of one of his books.
>
> [As Lessig explained it](http://web.archive.org/web/20050326032832/http://www.lessig.org/blog/archives/002782.shtml), with the new license, which has been given the designation of CC-Wiki, "rather than requiring attribution back to the copyright holder, [the license would] require attribution back to either the copyright holder or a designated entity." The designated entity would presumably be whatever organization controlled the wiki. Lessig characterized it as a newly branded version of the attribution/share-alike (CC-by-sa) license, rather than being an entirely new license."

The "new license" link in the quoted text takes you to `http://creativecommons.org/drafts/wiki_0.5`, which, as of this writing, redirects to `http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/`.  According to [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/), the "cc-wiki" link in the Stack Overflow footer has always linked to the CC-By-SA 2.5 license page since the [public beta in 2008](http://web.archive.org/web/20080915103343/https://stackoverflow.com/), until it was changed to point to the 3.0 version in [April 2011](http://web.archive.org/web/20110409233339/https://stackoverflow.com/).

So, to answer your literal question, apparently the "cc-wiki" designation is an obsolete synonym for CC-By-SA 2.5 that was adopted by SO in its early days and never updated, not even when the license version was changed.  IMO, it should be fixed, if only to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 5):

Not expert in this field of licence and attributions, but looks like Jeff was under the impression those two are the same, as he wrote in the [Attribution Required blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

> All the content contributed to Stack Overflow or other Stack Exchange sites is [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (**aka** [cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) licensed, intended to be **shared and remixed**.

From quick Google search looks like he wasn't the only one, but it's not really common though and I couldn't find the origin.