# The license on the stackexchange.com footer has the wrong name

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, licensing

On all of the Stack Exchange sites, user contributions are licensed **[CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)**. It says so in the footer and links to the license itself:

[image: user contributions licensed under cc-by-sa 3.0 with attribution required]

However, on https://stackexchange.com/, the license is incorrectly called **cc-wiki**:

[image: user contributions licensed under cc-by-sa 3.0 with attribution required]

Note that the link directs you to the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license page.

This naming error should be fixed.

Comment: Most likely an overlook, the text was [changed at some point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211815/why-don-t-we-call-our-licence-by-name) on all sites, but stackexchange.com runs on a separate code base so needs a manual update.

Comment: @Sha It wasn't...

Comment: @nicael yes it was, see my edit.

Comment: @Sha Ah, *that* long ago... Yes, I don't even recall the change... In  Dec 2013 I probably had a SO account with ~10 reps and nothing more.

Comment: @nicael yeah, I also didn't notice the change when it happened, but as the question itself proves, it did happen... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not surprised you didn't - who looks at the footer every day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I updated the text, the change will be out in the next Stack Exchange deployment (`build 7566`). Be aware that we don't deploy that site as much as the rest of the network, so it will happen *soon*.

Comment: When will this deployment happen?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος within [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος, Soon(TM).