# Meta and Stack Overflow footer broken

Tags: support, bug, design

When I reduced my browser size, the **footer** on Meta and Stack Overflow appears broken:

[image]

This happens on any other **Stack Exchange** site:

[image]

But it's working perfectly for Code Review (still in Beta).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209254/cc-logo-position-is-incorrect

Comment: What browser are you using? (looks ok here...)

Comment: @MarcGravell I checked in latest version of chrome `Version 31.0.1650.57 m` and FF.

Comment: @MarcGravell I even tried in [incognito window](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nkOHF.jpg) but still it is same.

Comment: I have tried in another machine too still the footer is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208203/top-bar-background-does-not-persist-when-scrolling-horizontally) I had asked recently

```
html{min-width:1000px;}
```

would also work here, because if I understand right, this bug occurs when you make the window small and scroll sideways, correct?

Comment: Yes this will fix, but it `html{min-width:100px;}` is already.  You have to change the value to `1000`

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan oops, typo

Comment: I remember doing the min-width: 1000px fix a while back but had to revert the change because it caused some problems on iPad, for reasons I don't remember. Can you confirm if this fix works with all browsers? (e.g. latest IE, FF). I know it works for desktop Chrome.